# C++/Qt5: Get a random image file from specified location

Tags: c++, qt, random, qt5, qimage

Given a folder and subfolders all containing jpeg files, what function can  I write an function to pull a random file from it, every time the function is called.

For example say we have the follwing directory structure:

```
root_directory/
    ├── image_1.jpg
    ├── child_directory_1/
    │   ├── image_1.jpg
    │   └── image_2.jpg
    └── child_direcory_2/
        ├── child_directory_2_1/
        │   └── image_1.jpg
        └── child_directory_2_1/
            └── image_1.jpg
```

Is there a way to open a random image when the location of `root_directory` is specified.

Comment: Please revise your spelling and explain "to random image"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion would be, use the [qdirEntryList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList):

1. set the root to `root_directory`
2. then search all the images using a filter(png, jpg or what you need) and
3. after that, generate a pseudo random number between 0 and `list.size()`
4. and use that as index for getting the path of the image,
5. that finally you will use in the constructor of the QImage Object you are going to return.